# Javascript setUTCDate & getUTCDate Methods Don't Show Time in UTC, Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a timestamp in UTC.  Here is what I'm trying, but the alert pop-up is showing the date in GMT+2, despite the setUTCDate and getUTCDate methods being used.  Why is this happening?

```
    // Get Number of Days Until Expiration
    var expDays = $('input[name=exp-field]').val(); 
    // Create Timestamp
    var expDate = new Date();
    expDate.setUTCDate( expDate.getUTCDate() + parseInt(expDays) );
    alert("expDate is: " + expDate);
    // Convert to seconds
    var finalDate = Math.round( expDate.getTime() / 1000 );
```

Comment: Welcome to the hell that is JavaScript dates

Comment: If you're *setting* the time with the UTC methods, that doesn't mean you're *showing* it with the UTC methods. The alert is easy to fix, though. And your `finalDate` timestamp is correct already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your alert you are doing a concat between a String and a Date, the method `toString` of the Date object is called, instead the `toUTCString` method should be called, so I think you should change your code to:

```
alert("expDate is: " + expDate.toUTCString());
```

`finalDate` should be fine though, as you could see from the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime